# Xamarin.Android EditText events not firing on device

Tags: android, xamarin, android-edittext

I have a Xamarin.Android application and running into an issue where events on an EditText field aren't firing on my device. They work on the simulator but not my Nexus 5X. Any Thoughts?

Layout

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/usernameTextField"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/LoginTheme.EditText"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:hint="user name"
android:lines="1"
android:maxLines="1"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topBorder"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintWidth_max="350dp" />
```

Code

```
UsernameTextField = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.usernameTextField);
    PasswordTextField = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.passwordTextField);


UsernameTextField.KeyPress += (sender, e) => {

    if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter && e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down) {
        this.PasswordTextField.RequestFocus();
    }
};
UsernameTextField.KeyPress += (sender, e) => {

    if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter && e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down) {
        this.PasswordTextField.RequestFocus();
    }
};

PasswordTextField.KeyPress += (sender, e) => {

    if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter && e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down) {
        this.DoLogin ();
    }
};
```

I have also tried using IME actions such as this.

```
UsernameTextField.EditorAction += HandleEditorAction;
PasswordTextField.EditorAction += HandleEditorAction;

private void HandleEditorAction(object sender, TextView.EditorActionEventArgs e) {
        e.Handled = false;
        if (e.ActionId == ImeAction.Send) {
        }
}
```

Nothing seems to work. When I hit the enter button on the virtual keyboard it just creates a new line in the EditText field. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

And as usual five minutes after posting this I found the solution. For whatever reason adding and inputType to the EditText seems to fix the problem and the KeyPress events are now working. Maybe this is a bug within Xamarin?

Comment: It didn't help me. Please, check my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474063/xamarin-android-key-listener-not-working?noredirect=1#comment91895458_52474063